# Testing if two samples have the same probability distribution

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, two-sample

I have a sample of N integer values and I would like to check the null hypothesis $H_0 \equiv $ "the sample has a Poisson($\lambda$) distribution"

This is, $p_i = P\{X=i\} = e^{-\lambda} \dfrac{\lambda^{i}}{ i!}, i=0,1,...$

So I've tried two approaches, both taken from the book "Simulation" 3rd edition from Ross.

First, I would take the sample and perform the "Chi-Square" test.
The other approach I took is generating a *theoretical* sample of N random variables with Poisson($\lambda$) distribution and then perform what the author calls the "Two Sample Problem" where one tests the null hypothesis

$H_0 \equiv $ "the variables from the two samples are all independent and identically distributed"

using a Rank Sum Test

The problem I'm facing is that in the Chi-Square method the p-value is high enough to accept the null hypothesis but in the two sample problem it's not.

For example, let $observedSample = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]$ the sample I wanna see if it has a Poisson($\lambda=0.495)$ distribution.

The p-value obtained with the Chi-Square test is 0.161 which is not low enough to reject the null hypothesis (The textbook says it should be rejected when it's around 0.05 or 0.01)

Now let $theoreticalSample = [1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]$ be the generated sample for the two sample test.

Here I get a p-value of 6.259e-09 which would lead to reject the null hypothesis.

Is one of these two approaches "more correct" than the other? Should I be using some other method instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get the estimate $\lambda=0.495$?  That appears inconsistent with the observed sample.  How did you generate the "theoretical sample"? It appears inconsistent with $\lambda=0.495$, too! Regardless, this "two sample problem" approach is seriously flawed because of the relatively large uncertainty in the information contained in such a small "theoretical sample." For it to work, the "theoretical sample" would need to be so large that its frequencies conform nearly perfectly with Poisson frequencies.

Comment: Hi @whuber. The lambda parameter was obtained because it's a Binomial(n,p) with n=10000 and p=4.95e-05 so it approximates to a Poisson with $\lambda = np$ if I'm correct.
I generated the theoretical sample with numpy:
    numpy.random.poisson(lam=0.495, size=20)

So, if I generate a theoretical sample of M large enough the two sample problem would be more accurate? And how large would it need to be? Do I need to increase also the observed sample size or it's not necessary? The algorithm works with $N \neq M$, but would it be valid from a statistical point of view?

Thanks for the reply

Comment: Could no longer edit the comment. Here's the one line of code to generate the theoretical sample:
`numpy.random.poisson(lam=0.495, size=20)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will simplify your question as much as possible.

Here we are mainly looking at the very few first values of the Poisson distribution, A $\chi^2$ is suitable. To avoid any side problem let's define two categories  : $A=\{0\};B=\{>0\}$. (I don't want to bother with the >5 limit in $\chi^2$). You always have exactly 20 trials: it is enough to describe the thing with the frequency of $A$ only. Theoretical value (for Poisson with $\lambda=0.495$) is 12.2.

First, let's do a simple goodness of fit. You have observed 16 vs. theoretical 12.2: p-value = 13%. Your simulated sample is 10. It lies on the other side of the confidence interval. p-value against theoretical : 43.5%  Now, if we test 16 against 10 in a two sample test (contingency table) we get p-value = 4.7%.

Summary :

- Fact 1 : probability to see a difference >3.8 when theoretical is 12.2 is 13%
- Fact 2 : probability to see a difference >2.2 when theoretical is 12.2 is 43.5%
- Fact 3 : probability to see a distance >6 when theoretical is 13 (avg. of 16 and 10): 4.7%

The difference between 12.2 and 13 is negligible. I suppose they're equal and won't even talk about them. Finally I round the numbers for easier reading :

- Fact 1 : probability that difference to theoretical value > 4 : 13%
- Fact 2 : probability that difference to theoretical value > 2 : 44%
- Fact 1 + 2 : probability to see both on two samples : $0.13 \times 0.44$ = 5.7 % (independence)
- Fact 3 : probability that difference between the two samples > 6 : 4.7%

It is logical that these two probabilities are close (without questioning geometry and logics too much).

The main reason why you reject 16 vs 10 is that **the generated sample is sufficiently far from the theoretical value, (and by chance opposite to your data sample)**, to cause a sufficient modification of the p-value, approximately equal to multiplying it by the p-value of your generated sample.

> The other approach I took is generating a theoretical sample of N
>   random variables with Poisson(λ) distribution and then perform what
>   the author calls the "Two Sample Problem" where one tests the null
>   hypothesis

To me, this is a strange method. It brings additional random for nothing.

Comment: Hi Benoit. Thank you very much for the detailed answer. 
Can I use the approach of "grouping" results: For example, if $\lambda$ was 4.95 instead of 4.95, can I say $A =  \{ < 5\}$

Comment: You can:  you must make sure all categories have enough samples in it. But this method is far from perfect. "0" should be considered "more <0" than "4" and this methods fails to take this into account. For continuous variables, you should use something like a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test). The higher $\lambda$, the more you should use a method close to a continuous variable. But my knowledge is very limited about it. This question is worth asking separately imo : how to test Poisson(5)...

Comment: I meant "more <5" (not "more <0")